# Symbolic Integration of definite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Actually, I want to solve, numerically, the following integral equation for the values of x for the range {y, 1, 5}, but I do not obtain any kind of solution.

```
e = 1.6*10^(-19);
h = 6.59*10^(-16);
v = 0.53*10^6;
n1 = 8*10^15;

Δ = 0.0665*5.69*10^-12;

t = (6*8.617*10^-5);

Γ = 0.0005;

ω = (h*y)/Δ;

A = FindRoot[(Sum[(Integrate[(Exp[-2*((-ω*(2*n + 1) + 2*g)/(2*
  Γ))^2]/(1 + Exp[(g - x)/t])), {g,  0, ∞}]), {n, 0, 100}]) ==
  ((n1*2*Pi*Γ*Sqrt[Pi])/(y*Sqrt[2])), {x, 0.01}][[1]];
```

Comment: Are you sure an analytical solution exists?

Comment: There is no analytical solution to integral of the form `Exp[z^2]/(1 + Exp[z])` which your function is basically of this form. i.e. You can't find a function whose derivative is `Exp[z^2]/(1 + Exp[z])`  So no need to try.

Comment: Nasser, how can solve this type of integral? Please help me.

Comment: You could try numerical integration. But you need actual numerical values for the variables `t,u,x,z` in this case. Like this ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Na7ti.png)

Comment: Nasser, I edit my code...Please help me to solve this numerically.

Comment: Again, the integral do not have analytical solution. Need to use numerical integration. But for that, need to have all parameters, other than the integration variable itself, be numerical and have known values. You updated integral is still not numerical. `n` and `y` are in it as symbols. Which means the integral will not work as is. I also do not understand why you put code that is not used. What is `e` there for?  and where is `n1` used? how about `v` ? Where is it used?

Comment: In my code, there is sum over n. Along y range i.e. {y, 1, 5}, I want to generate values for x variable. Value of e and v does not use in code, whereas h and n1 are used in numerical evaluation as evident in expressions of omega and A. Further, I want to solve expression A numerically and generate data from it for range {y, 1, 5}.

Comment: Anyone can solve this code.........

Answer (score 0):

Although, as noted by [Nasser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/70/nasser) in comments above, no symbolic solution exists for the integrals in the question, an upper bound can be obtained by setting the denominator, `(1 + Exp[(g - x)/t]`, to unity in the integrand.  Then,

```
Integrate[Exp[-2*((-ω*(2*n + 1) + 2*g)/(2*Γ))^2], {g, 0, Infinity}]
(* E^(4.61853*10^-14 (0.5 + 1. n)^2 y^2) (0.000313329 + 
   0.000313329 Erf[(2.46301 + 4.92602 n) y]) *)
```

which is well approximated by 0.000617 unless `n y` is very large or `y` is very near zero.  Thus, an upper bound on the sum of integrals is `0.000617 n`.  Yet, the question seeks values of `x` for which the integrated sum is equal to

```
n1*2*Pi*Γ*Sqrt[Pi]/(y*Sqrt[2])
(* 3.14992*10^13/y *)
```

Hence no zeroes can exist except at very large values of `n y`, well beyond the range given in comments above.